# How to Update SharePoint Item Permissions with SharePoint Designer

Tags: permissions

I'm trying to change folder permissions on item change by  calling a workflow - It works when I run the workflow the first time, but does not change permissions when I run the workflow on item change... and ideas ?

:Designer [image: selecting folder][image: setting permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select "Start workflow automatically when an item changed" setting [image]

Resolution: run workflow impersonation step with site collection admin.

Comment: Hi Thanks, I did that and the workflow does run but it throws an error and permissions are not changed..

Comment: Is the workflow running with system admin account (or)under impersonation?

Comment: under impersonation

Comment: is it SharePoint 2010 workflow? then run workflow with team site admin account and try again.

Comment: Ho do I set it to run as teamsite admin?

Comment: Open SPD with admin account using run as different user  (or) login your system with admin account

Comment: You must use account which is site collection admin in SP Designer and republish workflow under him. Now if you run workflow it will run under its privilegies... I wroted it in first Comment.

Comment: Yes, i just given your comments as reply...

Comment: this needs to be done even if the block of code is in an impersonation step?

Comment: yes we can, the problem got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have replacing action in **IF statement**, be sure IF statement is always true, if you want always change the permissions. Best way is remove the IF statement.

If this is not problem, will be logged "*GOT HERE TOO*" if workflow is run on item change?

Is this workflow published as SC administrator, so this workflow run under this administrator account?

Comment: GOT HERE TOO was in fact put to see if the IF statement is always true.. and it is.... I get GOT HERE TOO and then I get An error has occurred in ChangePermissions_ABC2. right at the Replace Permissions step....

Comment: And the error message? Did you try do 2 actions with replace and split these CASF_Contribute and Current Item:CASF_Contribute after it?

Comment: The error message only says "An error has occurred in ChangePermissions_ABC2".. maybe I should check logs on server I forgot to do that..

did not split but i did replace the two to one single permission to see if that works and the same happens

Comment: Any hints what I should look for in the log file?

Comment: In ULS log you should find the same message "An error has occurred in ChangePermissions_ABC2" and look what happened before.

I wanted you to split if error occurs on first or second replace permission aciton.

Comment: ULS has no such logs or anything that seems related (is it possible?)

Comment: This is now outside interest now, i asked your firstly if you have published this workflow under administrator, if you changing permissions, you cannot use impersonation because this user wont have permissions when it replacing them...